# How to set the permanent value of variable in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, variables, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating a jquery ui sortable with cookies to maintain the state when updated.

Here's the important part of the code:

```
for(i=0; i<counter; i++) {
    var connect = "";
    var count = 0;
    var tipo = "tipo" + i;
    for(j=0; j<counter; j++) {
        if(j != i) {
            if(count > 0) {
                connect = connect + ",.tipo" + j;
            }
            else {
                connect = ".tipo" + j;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    $( "." + tipo ).sortable({
        connectWith: connect,
        dropOnEmpty: "true",
        opacity: 0.8
    });

    $(".tipo" + i).sortable({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var order = $( "." + tipo ).sortable('toArray');
            createCookie(tipo, order, 1);
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var order = $( "." + tipo ).sortable('toArray');
            createCookie(tipo, order, 1);
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var order = $( "." + tipo ).sortable('toArray');
            createCookie(tipo, order, 1);
        }
    });

}
```

The problem that I've is that `var tipo = "tipo" + i;` will become `tipo2` in the last statement and all of the previous `createCookie(tipo, order, 1);` will have `tipo` as `tipo2` instead of `tipo0` or `tipo1`.

I hope you understand what I'm saying. If not, just tell me!

But, how can I make this have the right `tipo`?

Comment: Please reed [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures), the "loops" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the article I linked to boils down to is that there is only one `tipo` because the variable exists in the same scope. `for` loops don't create a new scope for each iteration.

You need to freeze the variable in a new scope, which is only possible with *functions* in JavaScript. I also recommend using `var` for all variables (i.e. all your loop counters).

```
for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  (function() {
    var tipo = ...;
    // `tipo` is not changed by a second iteration because this is a new scope

    ...
  })();
}
```